# what is the difference and what is better to use: Factory Function vs Constructor Function. Please reason your approach, so I can learn

Tags: javascript, oop

I have two functions that do the same thing (I may be wrong, but seems like they do the same thing in my newbie opinion):

```
// Factory Function
function createCircle(radius) {
    return {
        radius,
        draw: function() {
            console.log('draw');
        }
    }
}
const newCircle = createCircle(2);
console.log(newCircle);
```

And

```
// Constructor Function
function Circle(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.draw = function() {
        console.log('draw')
    }
}
const another = new Circle(2);
console.log(another);
```

Are there some pros and cons of these approaches? Just seeking for the opinions of more experienced developers.

Comment: "in your opinion" - SO is not a good place to ask opinion-based questions

Comment: @JanStránský Noted. Thanks

Comment: Remove "opinion" from the question and it becomes "what is the difference between these two things", which I think is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @JanStránský Already done

Comment: @JanStránský So, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most circumstances I'd say the constructor function is better.

- It lets you check whether the object is a Circle by using the `instanceof` operator (i.e. `circle instanceof Circle`)
- It makes the code more readable - when someone sees `new Circle` they know that a class is being instantiated, and they know that it will have a predictable behaviour, whereas for the first case they need to check the function definition (or documentation) of `createCircle` before they know anything about what this function is returning.
- You can optimise the constructor a little more - if you define the `draw` function on the [class's prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#The_prototype_property_Where_inherited_members_are_defined) (i.e. `Circle.prototype.draw = function(){/*etc*/}`) then it doesn't get declared each time you call `new Circle`.

That said, if you're creating an object with just a few properties and no methods then using the first example is perfectly reasonable.